# Why is WINAPI so redundant?

Tags: winapi

I just started looking at the WINAPI, and the first thing I noticed on the Windows Data Types webpage is redundancy. For example LONG32 is declared in BaseTsd.h as

```
typedef signed int LONG32;
```

and INT32, also declared in BaseTsd.h

```
typedef signed int INT32;
```

DWORD is declared in IntSafe.h as

```
typedef unsigned long DWORD
```

while ULONG is declared in WinDef.h as

```
typedef unsigned long ULONG;
```

Why are there different data types, if they are all the same in practice?

Also, we have this

```
typedef HANDLE HCONVLIST; //A handle to a DDE conversation list.
typedef HANDLE HDC; //  A handle to a device context (DC).
typedef HANDLE HDDEDATA; // A handle to DDE data.
```

Why are there different data types, if they are all of type HANDLE?

Comment: Also, in regards to `HANDLE`, most handle types are not actually the same type at all when [`STRICT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383732.aspx) is enabled. Most handle types are declared using the `DECLARE_HANDLE()` macro, so they map to unique struct types when `STRICT` is enabled, and map to `void*` when `STRICT` is disabled. But they are not simple typedefs of `HANDLE` like you have shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decisions on this were made about [40 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647982/why-does-the-win32-api-have-so-many-custom-types), at a time when there were no well established C standards. The API is still working today. Software written 30 years ago targeted for Windows 3.1 has a big chance of still running under Windows 10. Not many APIs have survived such a long time, or are used by so many developers.

Typedefs like `HDC` add another level of indirection, but make the intention more clear. An `HDC` variable should point to a device context and not to something else. It is similar to using something like `typedef unsigned int Age;` to make it clear that a variable should store an age value and not something else, like a port number, for instance.

Comment: What's more, abstractions like `HDC` also add a level of safety. Once you [enable the `STRICT` preprocessor symbol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383681.aspx), API calls expecting an `HWND` will fail to compile, when passed an `HDC`. I'm not sure when this was added, or whether it was a factor in the decision, but it sure is valuable in protecting the weakest link in software development (the developer).